# Explorer font anti-aliasing bug when rendeirng generated text over image

Tags: fonts, explorer, antialiasing

I`m using JQuery to load a JPEG image (as a css background) with some text over it.

The text renders fine in every browsers except Explorer (6 and 7 on XP, and 8 on W7), where the anti-aliasing transparency is done against the color black instead of the image.

If I load the image and text directly in the HTML, it works fine, so the problem occurs only if the text and image are changed dynamically with Javascript.

How can I make Explorer aware of the background image when rendering the text?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.

I forgot to mention I was animating the opacity of the text block; JQuery use Explorer CSS filter to achieve the animation.

When the animation is completed, you end up with:

```
<DIV id=banner_text style="DISPLAY: block; FILTER: alpha(opacity=100); ZOOM: 1" jQuery1288626313662="24">
```

You need to remove the filter from the style attribute (when the animation is completed):

```
$('#banner_text').css('filter','');
```